# JS HighCharts.js Pie data undefined error in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am having a bit of an issue with the following code:

```
//The Code:

    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {       //looping through data received
        var obj = mydata[i];      //current obj in loop
        var newObj = {      //creating new obj with same structure as the 'data' that works
            name: obj.name,
            y: obj.subhere.subhere1,
            id: i   

        };

        data.push(newObj);      //pushing each object into the data array
    }


//THE DATA:
var data = [{ name: 'Name 1', y: 20, id: 0 },{ name: 'Name 2', y: 10, id: 1 },{ name: 'Name 3', y: 10, id: 2 }];


//THE CHART CODE:
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

   series:[
      {
         "data": data,
          type: 'pie',
          animation: false,
          point:{
              events:{
                  click: function (event) {
                      //alert(this.id);
                  }


              }
          }          
      }
   ],
   "chart":{
      "renderTo":"container"
   },
});

//The above with create a pie chart with 3 names

//The Data

var mydata =[{

    "001":{

        "name":"Name 1",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":2
        }

    },
    "002":{

        "name":"Name 2",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":20
        }

    },


}];
```

The console is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: obj.subhere is undefined y: obj.subhere.subhere1,
```

I can see that the subhere.subhere1 names actually exists so in theory it should not be giving me an error, right?.

How can I fix this issue ... any ideas?

Comment: Does the error message give a line number?

Comment: I can't change data or mydata if you mean changing these variables as it's the way I've been given it so the code must work around the data as the data format cannot be changed sadly :-/

Comment: Yes @JonathanM - the error points to this line of code:  

y: obj.subhere.subhere1,

Comment: I don't see that line of code in your example.

Comment: You have the string `001` as a property name, but in your for loop you're looking for the property that is the just `1`. So the sub object is not found and you're getting the error.

Comment: Any ideas on how I could change it for it to work?

Comment: I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myData doesn't look correctly formatted. It has an extra comma after the bracket before last:

```
},
```

}];

You can loop through your object properties:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {       //looping through data received
    var obj = mydata[i];      //current obj in loop
    for(var key in obj){
      var newObj = {      //creating new obj with same structure as the 'data' that works
          name: obj[key].name,
          y: obj[key].subhere.subhere1,
          id: i   

      };
    data.push(newObj);      //pushing each object
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, that code change got rid of the error but the pie change is only showing 1 name (which is the last name - name 2), and there's 2 ...so there's an issue with the loop?

Comment: Move the push within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To work with your existing code, you could change the definition of mydata to this:

```
var mydata =[

    {

        "name":"Name 1",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":2
        }

    },
    {

        "name":"Name 2",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":20
        }

    }


];
```

Comment: That's the problem here. I can change the code but cannot change the data :-/   -- The 001 and 002 etc can be 657 or 557 it's not a numerical counter